# PTIJ: Performing Hagala or Libun to Kasher ones hands

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There's a din of Kebolo Kach Polto<sup>1</sup>, which means that the same way a taste enters something, is how it leaves. Therefore, does someone that burns their hand while handling hot food, have to burn it ***again*** to remove the flavor absorbed in their hand(s)?

Examples:

Touching hot non-kosher food should treif their hand.

Touching hot cholent should make their hand Fleishig.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Avodah Zarah 75b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.75b?lang=bi)</sub>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I think shaylos that are actually dealt with by poskim are disqualified for Purim Torah.

Comment: What's the joke here? I don't get it.

Comment: @user6591 Indeed, if it's a duplicate of a real question on site, it's clearly not PTIJ

Comment: @Double does it have to be a duplicate to get closed? I think this is more comparable to the cat that jumped into the chulent where Chassam Sofer says ein chai boleia than it is to the teeth question.

Answer (score -1):

Really you would have had to Kasher your hands. But since you would get large medical bills, the rabbis instituted an exemption, based on the law that:  הקב"ה חס על ממונו של ישראל.